# Change opacity of background img as element animates over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

```js
animateLense();

function animateLense() {
  $( "#lense" ).animate({
    left: "200px",
    top: "150px",
  }, 2000 );
}
```

```css
.bg-blurry {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.bg-clear {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.lense {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img class="bg-blurry"  src="http://www.atlantisbahamas.com/media/Things%20To%20Do/Water%20Park/Beaches/Gallery/waterpark_covebeach.jpg">
  <img class="bg-clear"  src="http://www.atlantisbahamas.com/media/Things%20To%20Do/Water%20Park/Beaches/Gallery/waterpark_covebeach.jpg">
  <div class="lense" id="lense"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to have a background image with an opacity of 0 got to 1 as another element animates across it? For example:

Imagine I have a `div class=bg-img` `300px by 300px` and another `div class=small-box` that is `100px by 100px`. As the `small-box` slides across the `bg-img`, left to right, it changes the `bg-img` opacity from 0 to 1. Kind of like a magnifying glass would work.. but changing the opacity ONLY within the `small-box` and nowhere else.

Appreciate any time spent on helping me with resolving this issue. =)
This may be achievable through canvas. I am just not talented enough to figure out how!

So in the example provided I have a blurry img and a clear one. The clear has been set to and opacity of 0. I want to be able to get it so that the clear img opacity is 1 inside the box. Maybe there is a different approach on this as well. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the code you are working with and some examples of what you've attempted?

Comment: And small-box should be draggable, i guess? Your current HTML/CSS/js setup would help, for sure. And this could be good starting point: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: I add some code as to what I am working on thus far. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you could use box-shadow:

basic example below:*(in your case: `parent{position:relative;overflow:hidden;}` `child {position:absolute;/* size and coordonates to your needs*/}` child moving on hover or via an animation or javascript.*

```css
div {
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1600px, inset 0 0 2em;
  transition:1s;
  }
html {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600);
  background-size:cover;
  }
html:hover div {
  top:50%;
  left:80%;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Pretty clean solution! I'm going to give it a shot and report back! =) Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The following would probably only work in similar use cases to what you've described above:

You could add the image as a background on `div.small-box` instead. If you set the `background-size` to `300px`, you should be able to animate the `background-position` when the `small-box` animates across `div.bg-img`.

Hope that helps. I can set up a demo on CodePen if you want.